# Can I edit the code of my question if I haven't received any answers and comments yet?

Tags: discussion, editing

[I asked this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/98759/jquery-plugin-that-makes-a-div-slide-to-the-side-of-the-page-on-scroll) two days ago. The question was well-received with 4 upvotes yet I haven't received any answers and no one has commented it.

In the meanwhile, I developed an other entirely different plugin for which I'm more willing to receive a feedback than the one I posted (as it is a more complex plugin).

My question is: Since the question I asked received no interactions (apart from the upvotes), can I edit the code so I integrate my newly created plugin?